# How to fix a mistake I made updating Ubuntu 14.04.05 32-bit server

Tags: apt, server, updates, apache2

I was updating Ubuntu 14.04.05 server and used `sudo apt-get update` instead of `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Ubuntu 16.04 began to install on server.  I panicked and logged out.

How can I check Ubuntu 14.04.05 server? How can I find out if Ubuntu 16.04 has over-written Ubuntu 14.04.05 server and any other files?

I can login and log out of the server. I have a CDROM with Ubuntu 14.04.05 server and a full backup on the server.

Comment: Panicking during an apt-get command is generally not a good idea. But `sudo apt-get update` does nothing harmful, so just let it finish and then enter the originally planned command.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get update` does not change anything either by installing or uninstalling any software, all it does is refreshes the list of available software. Upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 as you did could only have been initiated by a different command which you can view in the terminal by searching in your recent bash history.

A distribution upgrade does not delete any of your stored files, it just updates the installed packages so that they are compatible with the updated release. Distribution upgrades are conservative about deleting old files. Usually after a distribution upgrade you will find many files from orphaned packages that are left over from the previous Ubuntu release that can be either ignored and left in the filesystem or else deleted manually.

In order to find what version of Ubuntu you are running run this command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

In order to show the last 20 commands that the currently logged in user ran:

```
history 20 # instead of 20 the number can be any integer from 1 to 1000
```

Comment: lsb_release -a     Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS xenial

Comment: History shows I issued "cmd sudo apt_get upgrade". Should I upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS? How do I do this using cmd line? @karel

Comment: The results of that command would be: `No command 'apt_get' found, did you mean: Command 'apt-get' from package 'apt' (main)` and it would do nothing. In addition the results of `lsb_release -a` say that you are currently using Ubuntu 16.04, so trying to upgrade it to 16.04 again would also do nothing.

Comment: I get many errors when I run applications on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. These did not occur when I had Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS installed. How can I  revert to using Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS server? I have a DVD backup with Ubuntu 14.04.05 server. How do I install Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS server? Would appreciate your advice @karel

Comment: What I would do in your situation is to download Ubuntu Server 16.04, install it by overwriting the existing Ubuntu Server, and upgrade it to Ubuntu Server 18.04 in April when 18.04 is released. That way you're good until April, 2023.

Comment: That is an excellent idea. I will do that. @karel